# Installing R for Jupyter

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I'm having an issue installing R for Jupyter. It seems like the instructions are outdated. I installed the latest version of Anaconda. I'm running R 3.4.1. The following is the R script that is supposed to install the necessary kernel. I'm running this in RGui and RStudio. Both fail.

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘digest’

This makes no sense as I'm getting a message that says, digest was unpacked in the first step.

Error in IRkernel::installspec() : 
  jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"jupyter" kernelspec --version' had status 127

Answer (score 1):

We can also configure R using conda in Jupyter. Open your command prompt and execute the following line.

```
conda install -c r r-essentials
```

If you don't want to install R-essentials in your current environment, then execute the following line.

```
conda create -n my-r-env -c r r-essentials
```

This will install r-essentials into a new environment.

For more information, follow this link.

https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/jupyter-notebook-r

Answer (score 0):

I was working on windows. The common advice was to work in R terminal and not RStudio. That still didn't work. The key was to add C:\Users\[user name]\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client to my path variable.

Comment: I had the same issue. The problem was that I had two parallel R sessions running.

Comment: I might be struggling with that too. I noticed that when I asked for the version of R I was running, I got a different answer if I asked in RStudio or in the console.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working in RStudio:

- Make sure you the location of **python.exe** and **jupyter.exe** is added to your `PATH` variable (you can add it just for the session going to the prompt and running `SET PATH=%PATH%;"insert path; insert path2` and then running **rstudio.exe** from the same command prompt session)

Answer (score 0):

The following installation steps worked for me:

```
> conda create -n r_env r-essentials r-base
> source activate r_env
> conda install -c r r
> conda install -c r r-irkernel
```

Then while creating a new jupyter notebook, select R kernel.